# Dropping mssql data records for records older than xx days

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-delete

I'm trying to drop all the records from my DB where the records are OLDER than 3 days.

I've written something like this:

```
delete from Results WHERE [Date] > DATEADD(d, -3, getdate())
```

I wanted to check whether this sql query is correct since I'm worried that I might make a mistake and delete more than I should...

this this query correct?

Comment: removed incompatible mysql tag

Comment: Do a select with the same condition.

Comment: Create testdata and try it out

Comment: Are you practicing with production data?!? Never, ever do that. Have a test database where you try new queries! (And why delete old data?)

Comment: make a copy of the table, insert some data and test it - no it is not correct. Your date should be smaller than the expression

Comment: Test using transactions, if your result is correct commit it if not roll back

Comment: @jarlh yep it's a production data =D ... I'm transferring the data now to my local computer to see if it's gonna be alright :)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk you mean like this: delete from Results WHERE [Date] < DATEADD(d, -3, getdate())

Comment: < instead of > ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is deleting everything **newer** than 3 days old, and should be:

```
DELETE FROM Results WHERE [Date] < DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())
```

Otherwise, this is fine for deleting everything that is older than exactly 72 hours, although as others have said you should definitely be testing either on a copy of the data or at least by using SELECT statement

```
SELECT * FROM Results WHERE [date] < DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())
```

However, if you want to delete everything that happened before *three days ago* (e.g. It is now Monday, and I want to delete everything that happened before Friday) you would need to eliminate the time aspect.

```
DELETE FROM Results WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [date]) < DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Always check WHERE clause in SELECT clause before update or delete statement :

```
SELECT DATEADD(d, -3, getdate())
```

First check your WHERE clause in SELECT statement.It gives your expected date means continue with same WHERE clause in DELETE.